# SQL Server not found or accesive error on MVC Movie tutorial program

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently getting my head around MVC ASP.NET and following this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller. I followed the whole tutorial to the letter but after I created the MoviesController like the tutorial said, and I press F5 and go to localhost:xx/Movies to try the code I get the following error:

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accesible

The code that causes this is `return View(db.Movies.ToList());` in the MoviesController.cs file (which is generated by Visual Studio after following the steps in the tutorial). I am currently using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate in Windows 7. The database is supposed to be a LocalDB instance generated as the tutorial explains.

Comment: I've found what's wrong. Entity Framework Code First should create the `Movies.mdf` file which contains the database automatically inside the App_Data folder, but no such file is created. How can I make sure that file is created? Does anyone know a workaround? I'm new in Visual Studio and SQL Server so I have no clue how to work with those databases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out LocalDB was broken. Reinstalling it fixed the issue.

Comment: How do you reinstall it?

Answer (score 0):

First please check that you define MovieDBContext in web.config file like

add name="MovieDBContext" connectionString="your sql connection string or your local db connection string" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient".

Because this MovieDBContext is establish connection with database.
And you get error of establishing a connection to SQL Serveronnection.

Comment: I did that exactly as the tutorial said in the previous step, still doesn't work. The string is `<add name="MovieDBContext"    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> `

Answer (score 0):

You may want to just be sure that you don't have an open connection to the database from Server Explorer. If you do, close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

try to give datasource = ".\SQLEXPRESS"

Answer (score 0):

change your connection string as

```
 <add name="MovieDBContext"    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

and try

Comment: have you connected to your database using sql server management studio?

Comment: Nope, the database is a LocalDB one which should be automatically generated by Entity Framework based on the Movie model object.